# Upside down orientation in iPhone app using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am developing an app and intend to use upside down orientation in it. I have used the following code

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        if toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
            self.shouldAutorotate()
        }
    }
```

But its not working. Any help!???

Comment: Yep! For landscape, options would be landscape left or landscape right I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Device orientation (General Tab):

[x] Portrait

[x] Upside Down

[ ] Landscape Left

[ ] Landscape Right

**Swift 2**

```
// UINavigationController+UpsideDownOrientation.swift

import UIKit
extension UINavigationController {

    public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return [.Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this on your plist file

```swift
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

And also verify on your target on *general tab* on *Deployment info* to have this:

[image]

On the other hand, are you using Navigation controller or Tab controller? If so, you will need to subclass navigation or tab controllers and add these two methods:

```swift
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your view controller code.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int{
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: Didn't help!  This upside down orientation is getting so hard to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your Class or ViewController.

```
  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
  return false 
 }  
  override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
  return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

Comment: Didn't work! This upside down orientation is getting so hard to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Add these two functions to the viewcontrollers that you want to set the orientation to. Works for Swift 3.0 because I'm using it right now.

On your project, under General, select the "Device Orientation" that you want the App to support. Then go to the .plist and edit the Supported interface orientations (iPad) for the orientation you want to support.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight // or .landscapeLeft or .portrait or .portraitUpsideDown which ever orientation you want the viewcontroller to be
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your info.plist for Supported interface orientations, set it as you wish

2) Check your deployment information and select your chosen device orientations